# lintOptions for experimental Gradle build tool in Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-experimental

As Android Studio 1.3 coming with NDK support, I tried to convert my Gradle scripts (build.gradle app/build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties) following this link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.

However, I cannot find any guidance about **lintOptions** from both the tutorial as well as ndk example repository https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

My app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 21
        buildToolsVersion = "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.abc.xyz"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
        }

        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        lintOptions {       // <-- this block
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }

        android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

The sync failed with log: Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig_Impl

If I remove the **lintOptions** block, it seems to sync OK but build fails later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be prefixed with "android." inside the model{ }

```
model{

  android.lintOptions {
       checkReleaseBuilds = false
  }
}
```

Comment: thank for your help, I will try it. However, I think the line inside lintOptions block should be **checkReleaseBuilds = false** since this is the new DSL style.

Comment: That's crazy simply moving it from inside Android block to outside and prefixing with android. fixes this. Why, aren't they equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm stating the obvious, but your code appears to have a stray }

```
    lintOptions {       // <-- this block
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
} // <-- Stray closes off the buildTypes info

    android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = true
    }
}
```